# How to assign column value to a variable within mySQL script ?

Tags: mysql

I have the following script but it returns null all the time.

```
    SELECT 
    @PRICE_LARGE_PRICE = PRICE_LARGE_PRICE,
    @PRICE_SMALL_PRICE = PRICE_SMALL_PRICE
FROM
    prices
WHERE
    PRICE_LISTING_ID = 60;

SET @ITEM_PRICE = (CASE Size WHEN GivenLargeSizeName THEN @PRICE_LARGE_PRICE 
WHEN GivenSmallSizeName THEN @PRICE_SMALL_PRICE 
ELSE null 
END);
```

The issue here is

```
@PRICE_LARGE_PRICE = PRICE_LARGE_PRICE,
@PRICE_SMALL_PRICE = PRICE_SMALL_PRICE
```

table returns PRICE_LARGE_PRICE & PRICE_SMALL_PRICE correctly but the assignment does not work. Hence CASE fails.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html):

```
SELECT PRICE_LARGE_PRICE, PRICE_SMALL_PRICE
INTO @PRICE_LARGE_PRICE, @PRICE_SMALL_PRICE
FROM prices
WHERE PRICE_LISTING_ID = 60;
```

Note that you need to ensure that the query only returns one row of data, using `LIMIT 1` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it always returns one record.listing I'd is primary key. I will check your code tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    @PRICE_LARGE_PRICE:=PRICE_LARGE_PRICE,
    @PRICE_SMALL_PRICE:=PRICE_SMALL_PRICE
FROM
    prices
WHERE
    PRICE_LISTING_ID = 60;
```

just add colon before equal sign in mysql

Comment: That's cute, I will try that too.